# Display all individual rows of a GROUP BY, sorted by the cardinality of the groups

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by

Given a table like this:

```
User     A
---------------
Erik     1278
Bob      16287
Alice    9723
Daniel   7
Erik     8
Bob      162
Erik     126
```

**how to select all lines, grouped/ordered by user with the highest number of rows?**

The result would be:

```
Erik     1278            # Erik is first because 3 rows with him
Erik     8
Erik     126
Bob      16287           # Bob is 2nd because 2 rows
Bob      162
Alice    9723
Daniel   7
```

Neither

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY user
```

nor

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) as frequency FROM t GROUP BY user ORDER BY frequency DESC
```

works, indeed the latter displays only one row for Erik, one row for Bob, one row for ...

It seems like I need a `GROUP BY`, but still be able to see "each row" of the group. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
order by count(*) over (partition by user) desc,
         user
```

The first key counts the number of rows per user.  The second keeps all users together (which is important if there are ties).  You can add a third key if you want for ordering the rows for each user.

EDIT:

In older versions, you can use a subquery:

```
order by (select count(*) from user u2 where u2.user= u.user) desc,
         user
```

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff for your answer. It seems `OVER (PARTITION ...)` requires a recent version of Sqlite3 (see https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history). Do you think there's a solution without this recent feature? I will try to update my Sqlite version but as it might break older tools using an older version, I'm also looking for another solution.